# How to draw different shapes by clicking a button in android?

Tags: android, button, drawing

I have been looking for help doing this, I am attempting to create a snake game, what I need to do is draw into a bitmap or into an image view while clicking a button, that's the problem: every time I draw a shape, then the layout is erased, the goal for me is to draw into any object while I can still click a button, what I have already done is to draw over a layout and displaying an image, here is my code:

```
public class DisplayMessage extends Activity {


ImageView image;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("Hola Jorge");
    DrawView drawView;

    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView(drawView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
    return true;
}

}


package mipaca;

public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN); 

        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
        Bitmap compara = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas.drawBitmap(compara, 0, 0, paint);

        Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,100,100);
        canvas.drawBitmap(compara, 0,0,null);

}

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CharSequence[] items = {"Google","Apple","Microsoft"};
boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[items.length];

ImageView image;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick2(View v)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessage.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ferrari_458_italia_1);
    showDialog(0);
    DrawView2 alpha;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch(id){
    case 0:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("Este es un diálogo con algo de texto")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", 

        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "bien, click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }



        }
        )
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "bien, click!",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }



        }
).create();


    }
    return null;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 50, p);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help someone, I forgot about this question until I came across with this idea: We can use an ImageView and then use a bitmap to draw any shape with a canvas, it is easier for me to draw in this way rather than using OnPaint function and invalidate because just modifying the bitmap and displaying it we can move an object on image and still have buttons, textboxs, etc. Here is what I have done:

(linen is our ImageView)

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);  
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bMap.getConfig();
if(bitmapConfig == null) {
bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
}
bMap = bMap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bMap);
paint.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 61, 61));
canvas.drawCircle(10, 10, 5, paint);        
linen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.View1);
linen.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```